# Email status in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I want to track emails that are being send by SES. I want to check if the email I am sending to my client is delivered or not. I found that AWS C# sdk provides the statistics, but it doesn't provide statistics per email address.

Answer (score 1):

From [Monitor email sending using Amazon SES event publishing - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-using-event-publishing.html):

> To enable you to track your email sending at a granular level, you can set up Amazon SES to **publish email sending events** to Amazon CloudWatch, Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose, or Amazon Simple Notification Service based on characteristics that you define.
>
> You can track several types of email sending events, including sends, deliveries, opens, clicks, bounces, complaints, rejections, rendering failures, and delivery delays. This information can be useful for operational and analytical purposes. For example, you can publish your email sending data to CloudWatch and create dashboards that track the performance of your email campaigns, or you can use Amazon SNS to send you notifications when certain events occur.